# "sudo pip" differs from normal "pip"

Tags: python, sudo, environment-variables, pip

When I execute

```
which pip3
```

it points to

```
/usr/.../anaconda3/bin/pip3
```

However, when I run

```
sudo which pip3
```

the result is

```
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Where does this problem comes from and how do I achieve that `sudo pip` also points to `/usr/.../anaconda3/bin/pip3`?

Comment: What are the outputs of `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: anaconda is only included in the second path

Comment: Really good question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo` sanitizes the environment before running any command. In doing so, if the value of the directive `secure_path` is set, it will be used as the `PATH` for the `sudo` commands, not the current `PATH`.

In my system:

```
% sudo grep -E 'secure_path' /etc/sudoers
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

So i have:

```
% echo $PATH
/home/foobar/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

% sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH' 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

---

What you can do to keep your current path or add `/usr/.../anaconda3/bin` to `sudo`'s `PATH`:

- Pass `PATH` in the environment of the `which` command:

  ```
  sudo PATH="$PATH" which pip3
  ```

  Any desired `PATH` can be set too.
- Keep the current environment while running `sudo` by:

  ```
  sudo -E which pip3
  ```
- Disable the `secure_path` value by putting a `#` in front or remove the line to keep the current `PATH`:

  ```
  # Defaults        secure_path="....."
  ```

  Instead, you can also modify the `secure_path` to just add `/usr/.../anaconda3/bin` to it, **at the beginning**.
- Add `PATH` to the `env_keep` directive to keep the `PATH` in the `sudo` provided environment:

  ```
  Defaults        env_keep += "PATH"
  ```