# Sudo /bin/bash -c 'some command' does not load /etc/environment content, not set the env

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, sudo, environment

I've got a bit confused

When I do log in via `sudo su -` 
I get full environment loaded

```
$ sudo su -
# env
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=screen-256color
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
HTTPS_PROXY_HOST=myproxy.com
HTTP_PROXY_PORT=3128
USER=root
(some other lines)

# cat /etc/environment
HTTPS_PROXY_HOST=myproxy.com
HTTP_PROXY_PORT=3128
```

But when I do execute a single command via sudo, the environment (specially /etc/environment) is not loaded

```
sudo -i -u root /bin/bash -c 'env'
TERM=screen-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
(some other lines)
NO LINES FROM /etc/enviromnment
```

Any clue?

System Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/a/781513

Comment: Both `sudo` and `su` have PAM configuration to read `/etc/environment`, but `sudo` then filters out environment variables as shown in @heemayl's answer